# Shopify filter operators

Tags: filter, operators, shopify

When using the shopify api call:

GET /admin/products.json?handle=fb-xxxx

what operators are available in place of the equals sign?  I am looking to only retrieve products the handle for which starts with "fb-"

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done like that. Best you could do is get them all and filter the results.